# storing output of pbinom (with multiple probabilities of success) in R

Tags: r, for-loop, probability

I am using `pbinom` in R to determine the p-values for multiple outcome values and probabilities of success:

```
1 - pbinom(1:2, 21, c(0.02, 0.05))
```

`1:2` represents the number of observed counts, 21 represents the sample size, and `0.02` and `0.05` represent the probability of success. However, the output of the above command is:

```
[1] 0.06534884 0.08491751
```

These values represent the probabilities of:

```
1 - pbinom(1, 21, 0.02) & 1 - pbinom(2, 21, 0.05)
```

respectively.

I wish to obtain the outputs of : `1 - pbinom(1:2, 21, 0.02)` and `1 - pbinom(1:2, 21, 0.05)`
such that I obtain the output:

```
[1] 0.065348840 0.008125299 ## pvalues for 1 - pbinom(1:2, 21, 0.02)
[1] 0.28302816 0.08491751 ## pvalues for 1 - pbinom(1:2, 21, 0.05)
```

My actual data set is very lengthy, so I can't type code for every probability of success.

I also tried this using a for loop:

```
output=c()
for (i in 1:2) {
output[i]=(1 - pbinom(i, 21, c(0.02, 0.05)))
}
```

But I get the following warning message:

> 1: In output[i] = (1 - pbinom(i, 21, c(0.02, 0.05))) :
>     number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
>   2: In output[i] = (1 - pbinom(i, 21, c(0.02, 0.05))) :
>     number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

I realize this question maybe difficult to interpret, but any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: you should use `pbinom(..., lower.tail = FALSE)` rather than `1 - pbinom`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will use this in my code to get P(X>x)

Answer (score 1):

Using sapply:

```
t(sapply( c(0.02, 0.05), function(x) 1 - pbinom(1:2, 21, x)))

#             [,1]        [,2]
# [1,] 0.06534884 0.008125299
# [2,] 0.28302816 0.084917514
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can try this,

```
matrix(1-pbinom(c(1:2,1:2), size=21, prob = rep(c(0.02,0.05), each=2)), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
```

PS : The error means that your vector is not of the same length of your input.